# Stack Overflow now thinks I am a spammer!

Tags: support, spam

I recently found an answer to a problem which lots of users were asking on Stack Overflow, and nobody had posted a complete answer yet:

[How to filter specific apps for ACTION_SEND intent (and set a different text for each app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730243/android-how-to-filter-specific-apps-for-action-send-intent/18068122#18068122)

I tried to find all the similar questions which my answer solved and linked to my answer. There were a lot of them! I think maybe somebody assumed I was spamming without looking carefully, because my posts were deleted and now I can't post at all because I had so many posts deleted! :(

Please take a look at this example: [Set a different text to an ACTION_SEND intent according to the application selected in the chooser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409931/set-a-different-text-to-an-action-send-intent-according-to-the-application-selec)

My answer is perfect for this question, but it was deleted!

This is my first attempt at posting on Stack Overflow. I would appreciate any help undeleting posts where appropriate and getting my account re-enabled.

Comment: Mass copy/pasting of answers is automatically detected by the system - this is normally indicative of spamming, in one form or another.

Comment: Link only answer are discouraged. Those should have been comments.

Comment: Now, all the deleted ones essentially a single **link** with a self-promoting blurb, not **full answers** to the _actual_ questions asked.

Comment: Also, please remember that this is *not a forum*, so do not reference comments/etc in your answer. Make it self contained and flow naturally from the question presented. Comments go away all the time, they are 9th class citizens.

Comment: Yep, somebody thought it was spam. Possibly because it was spam. Promoting your own answer with a ton of links, promoting your own product with a ton of links… it’s the same thing. Don’t, please.

Comment: For what it's worth, copy/pasting the same answer across multiple questions would be normal behavior on most forums and considered acceptable. Stack Overflow is different from other forums, which should have been clear from that banner you saw the first time you logged in. This kind of behavior is non-normative here and is not acceptable. A rookie mistake - no sweat. You may want to read the FAQ next time to avoid making additional mistakes - or you can just figure it out via SoHK.

Comment: And now, Meta Stack Overflow also thinks you are a spammer. For a reason...

Comment: @dacoinminster - coming here is the way to recover, so long as you show willingness to follow the rules (just saying for those who don't show such willingness when first posting here)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I looked *extremely* carefully. 19 hours ago, you posted 13 duplicate 'answers' of the following form:

> You might find this example helpful, which allows the user to choose between twitter, facebook, email, or SMS with custom text for each:
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/18068122/2647306
>
> It hides all the other stuff like sharing over wifi and bluetooth.

Those are not appropriate answers at all. You need to answer each question individually, and tailor your answer to them. If the questions are truly duplicates, you should flag/vote accordingly.

We appreciate your eagerness to help people, but please just keep this in mind.

Comment: Well, to vote/flag one requires 15 rep ;)

Comment: It seems the OP believes SO is a forum of sorts, based on the way he edited his original answer. Likely part of the problem.

Comment: @Oded Do'h! I *always* forget that! Next, you are going to tell me that all users don't have moderator powers!!

Comment: Thanks for the information. I apologize for breaking rules here. I guess I'll have to create a new account  that doesn't have a trashed reputation.

Comment: @dacoinminster: that too is not acceptable.

Comment: That's interesting. So I'm forever banned from posting under any account? That seems harsh.

Comment: @dacoinminster - Check again. You are now OK to answer more questions.

Comment: @dacoinminster - Sounds like your account has been cleared. For future reference, you might want to read this: [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Comment: @Oded - I thought moderators could not lift automatic bans. Has that changed?

Comment: @Cyborgx37: **Oh, Oded is *more* than a moderator.**

Comment: @Cyborgx37 - Nope, that has not. Though, as a dev I can do more than the mods. Having said that, it was automatically lifted.

Comment: @Oded Thanks! I was able to post again now. I'll try to make sure I customize answers in the future and not just link to another answer. Thanks for giving me another chance.

Comment: @dacoinminster: or, if your answer truly fits for all N questions...N-1 of them are duplicate questions! We have the means of marking them as such to reduce redundancy.

Comment: @dacoinminster - so instead of learning from this, you instead posted the same answer to [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409931/set-a-different-text-to-an-action-send-intent-according-to-the-application-selec/18087678#18087678) [nmore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313802/android-action-send-different-texts-for-each-application/18088020#18088020) questions?

Comment: @LBT I have *no idea* what you are talking about there... unless you are 10k, that is ;)

Comment: @AndrewBarber I was careful to customize my answer to exactly match those questions. Is the problem that the questions were too similar to each other? My answer is correct for both problems - would you be willing to help me format my answer so it passes your review?

Comment: @dacoin So changing *one sentence* counts as "customization" to you?

Comment: @dacoinminster Easy: Create a *new* answer for each.

Comment: @AndrewBarber That's sad, because the same code snippet is exactly what they need. Oh well, I won't try to fight you on it. I just really wanted to help other people who had the same problem I did.

Comment: @dacoinminster I guess the point would be: don't go _looking_ for other questions that your answer could apply to. But if you happen to find one, you can leave a comment saying something like "My answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192138/please-help-stackoverflow-now-thinks-i-am-a-spammer#comment599604_192140) might be useful for this." Or you could flag the question as a duplicate. (Or both)

Comment: @dacoinminster if you want to help people post a comment or flag as duplicate. Having a hundred copys of the same thing creates a maintenance nightmare.  Imagine I notice an error in one version amd correct it; there are still 99 wrong copies hanging about

Comment: @RichardTingle Excellent point. Though, it would offer an opportunity to sing, "99 errors in code in an answer, 99 errors in code; load one up, and fix the code; 98 errors in code in an answer!"